# ¿Cómo regresar al inicio de un programa con python?

Tags: python, formato-condicional

Estoy aun con este programa pero ahora quiero que se regrese a colocar el nombre para iniciar de nuevo el programa, aquí lo intente con un condicional `if`, pero me saca un error en el `return`, aun no entiendo bien para que sirve el `return` y como se usa, si el usuario colooca un numero diferente al 1,2,3 que se regrese al principio, gracias

```
import time
n=0
print("Programa para sacar notas de p1, p2 o p3")
time.sleep(1)
nombre=input("Escribe tu nombre aqui:  ")
print("Bienvenid@  = " + nombre + " =  para comenzar a calcular")
time.sleep(1)
elegir_corte = int(input("Escribe el corte que vamos a calcular (Ej: 1, 2, 3):  "))
if elegir_corte>4:
    return nombre
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El concepto de 'volver al principio' en lenguajes de programación modernos no existe, por lo menos no formulado de esa forma. Pero el flow de un programa se puede controlar usando estructuras de control como bucles, o llamadas a funciones.

Una solución posible es usar recursión, cuando una funcion se llama a si misma:

```py
def main():
    print('Dividamos dos numeros')

    n1 = float(input('Dividendo: '))
    n2 = float(input('Divisor: '))

    if n2 == 0:
        print('No se puede dividir por zero, intentalo de vuelta')
        return main() # Vuelve a llamarse a si misma
    else:
      print('Resultado:')
      print(n1 / n2)

main()
```

Otra solucion posible es usar un `while` loop, y saltar al proximo bucle usando `continue`:

```py
while True:
    print('Dividamos dos numeros')

    n1 = float(input('Dividendo: '))
    n2 = float(input('Divisor: '))

    if n2 == 0:
        print('No se puede dividir por zero, intentalo de vuelta')
        continue # Salta al proximo bucle
    else:
      print('Resultado:')
      print(n1 / n2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python no soporta "GoTo" o brincos a una line específica del código. En lugar de eso debes usar funciones de control

Una forma fácil de hacerlo es un 'Loop'

```
while True: 
   print("pedo")
```

En el ejemplo, el programa se queda "ciclado" en el while porque el valor nunca cambia de True a False

Answer (score 0):

Si lo quieres implementar con un ciclo if seria como el sig ejemplo:

```
elegir_corte = int(input("Escribe el corte que vamos a calcular (Ej: 1, 2, 3):  "))

if(elegir_corte == 1):
     print("entraste al corte 1")
elif (elegir_corte == 2):
         print("entraste al corte 2")
elif (elegir_corte == 3):
             print("Entraste al corte 3")
else:
                 print("esa opcion no esta disponible")
```

Para hacer que este ciclo se repita al caer en una sentencia que no sea 1 ,2 0 3 es decir en else: yo agregaría un contador y un ciclo where como en el sig ejemplo :

```
contador = 1
while( contador == 1):
    elegir_corte = int(input("Escribe el corte que vamos a calcular (Ej: 1, 2, 3):  "))

    if(elegir_corte == 1):
        print("entraste al corte 1")
        contador = 0
    elif(elegir_corte == 2):
         print("entraste al corte 2")
         contador = 0
    elif(elegir_corte == 3):
             print("Entraste al corte 3")
             contador = 0
    else:
         print("esa opcion no esta disponible")
         contador = 1
```

Claro que otra mejor opción seria usar una alternativa a switch case pero es mas avanzado de cualquier forma te dejo el enlace a un articulo [aqui](https://medium.com/@BryanMiranda/simular-un-switch-en-python3-35415520bf1f)

Comment: uy bro @_@ me acabas de desenredar para que sirven los bucles, claro ahora con ese ejemplo entiendo todoo bro, muchas gracias!!!!!!

Comment: De nada amigo ,no olvides votar por la respuesta ,saludos !.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo primero return es lo que devuelve en este caso tu programa al shell desde el que fue invocado, en este caso lo que estas devolviendo al shell es el numero introducido por el usuario. Esto es lo típico la respuesta de un comando, que tipicamente es 0 cuando todo va bien y un número distinto si ha habido algún problema, no obstante es preferible usar cuando tu código es el que se ejecuta principal la función exit antes que return.

Cuando el return está en una función el valor de return es lo que se le pasa a la funcion que lo invoca.

Por otro lado para "volver al principio" lo mejor es utilizar un bucle, y para que quede un "poco más claro", no queda mal encapsular el código que queremos que se repita en una funcion.

Por otro lado, tú comentas que quieres que salga si el número no es 1,2 o 3 y en tu código si te meten un número negativo o 0 también saldría, eso lo puedes corregir con chequeando que el resultado sea > 3 o menor que 1: if elegir_corte < 1 or elegir corte > 3:

No obstante un código que ejecuta lo que tú quieres te lo pongo aquí:

```
import time

def takeNumber():
    n=0
    print("Programa para sacar notas de p1, p2 o p3")
    time.sleep(1)
    nombre=input("Escribe tu nombre aqui:  ")
    print(nombre)
    print("Bienvenid@  {}  para comenzar a calcular".format(nombre))
    time.sleep(1)
    elegir_corte = int(input("Escribe el corte que vamos a calcular (Ej: 1, 2, 3):  "))
    print(elegir_corte)
    return elegir_corte

def main():
    numberToExit = (1,2,3)
    result = 0
    while not (result in numberToExit):
        result = takeNumber()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    exit(0)
```

Lo que hace es invocar a un método main() que es una buena práctica, y este método lo que hace es crear una tupla, con los números que te marcan el corte en este caso 1,2,3.

Luego se itera en un bucle while mientras el número no esté contenido dentro de tus números de salida (la palabra in devuelve true si el número está dentro de la tupla). Y luego se llama a una función que recoge el nombre de usuario y el número que introduce, esta función devuelve pues el número introducido al usuario, luego la función main chequea si está dentro del conjunto de números para salir, si es así no vuelve a iterar el bucle, si por contra no está dentro de ellos (por eso en la condición del bucle se pone el not) lo que hace es volver a pedir otro numero.

Y al sistema operativo se le devuelve con exit(0) siempre que el comando se ejecutó correctamente (por convenio).

Comment: buenas noches, amigo entendi codigo (soy principiante) pero no me cuadra:
esto no lo entendi:

while not (result in numberToExit):
        result = takeNumber()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
exit(0)

Comment: while not (result in numberToExit): -> Esta linea te esta diciendo mientras "result" no tenga un valor contenido en la tupla numberToExit ejecuta lo que está dentro del bucle /  result = takeNumber() -> te esta diciendo que ejecutes la funcion takeNumber, y almacenes lo que devuelve dicha funcion con return en "result".

Comment: la parte "if __name__ == '__main__': Indica que si este archivo es invocado desde la linea de comandos se ejecute esta parte. Y lo que ejecuta es main() y luego exit(0) "habia un error en la indentacion ya corregido", devuelve al shell desde el que fue invocado un 0. Tal y como esta ese codigo lo primero que ejecuta es main(), cuando acabe main, ejecuta exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que quizá no conoces lo que es una funcion en python, te lo dejo puesto sin hacer uso de funciones:

```
import time


numberToExit = (1,2,3)
result = 0
while not (result in numberToExit):
    n=0
    print("Programa para sacar notas de p1, p2 o p3")
    time.sleep(1)
    nombre=input("Escribe tu nombre aqui:  ")
    print(nombre)
    print("Bienvenid@  {}  para comenzar a calcular".format(nombre))
    time.sleep(1)
    elegir_corte = int(input("Escribe el corte que vamos a calcular (Ej: 1, 2, 3):  "))
    print(elegir_corte)
    result = elegir_corte
```

Y aquí te pongo el equivalente sin hacer uso de la tupla.

```
import time


result = 0
while result < 1 or result > 3:
    n=0
    print("Programa para sacar notas de p1, p2 o p3")
    time.sleep(1)
    nombre=input("Escribe tu nombre aqui:  ")
    print(nombre)
    print("Bienvenid@  {}  para comenzar a calcular".format(nombre))
    time.sleep(1)
    elegir_corte = int(input("Escribe el corte que vamos a calcular (Ej: 1, 2, 3):  "))
    print(elegir_corte)
    result = elegir_corte
```